# Oracle ROLLBACK not returning data

Tags: oracle, commit, rollback

I made a mistake in deleting data.  I did not run the commit statement after the delete, but when running ROLLBACK, the data is still missing.

I ran something like:

```
create table temp_ids as
select myid ABC --This might be part of the mistake as I did not alias this to my_id
from XX WHERE xx;
create index idx01 on temp_ids (my_id);

delete from YYY where my_id in (select my_id from temp_ids);
delete from XXX where my_id in (select my_id from temp_ids);
delete from ZZZ where my_id in (select my_id from temp_ids);
commit;
```

I was using sqldeveloper, and I hit the Cancel query button after the first 2 deletes (before it got to the commit).  But rolling back does not return the data in the first 2 tables.
Any other options?
I'm using Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

UPDATE:

~~~~~~~

As requested here is the full statement:

```
create table temp_events as
select 
DUP.Event_ID Dupl
from EVENT_REV MASID INNER JOIN EVENTS MAS ON MASID.Event_ID = MAS.Event_ID
left join EVENTS DUP
ON 
MAS.IMPACT = DUP.IMPACT AND  
INNER JOIN EVENT_REV DUPID ON DUPID.Event_ID = DUP.Event_ID 
WHERE 
MAS.person_id = 'JSteward'
ORDER BY MAS.event_id;
create index idx01 on temp_events(event_id);

delete from EVENT_REV where event_id in (select event_id from temp_events);
delete from EVENT_TASKS where event_id in (select event_id from temp_events);
--Here is where I hit the Cancel Query button and ran ROLLBACK.
delete from TIMESHEETS where event_id in (select event_id from temp_events);
delete from TRIPS where event_id in (select event_id from temp_events);
commit;
```

The temp_events table had about 800 records like:
C00156
C45568
C41155
D12355

Comment: Are you sure the data was there in the first place? Can you provide a complete example with some sample data?

Comment: Yes, there was definitely data there in the first place.  The complete sample might make the question a bit complex but I will do so anyway.

Comment: And you are also sure that the Autocommit functionality in SqlDeveloper (Preferences/Database/Advanced) is not turned on either?

Comment: What did the script output window show? And presumably you rolled back in the same session, without disconnecting? If the chafes were committed, do you have flashback enabled? e.g. `select * from event_rev as of timestamp <some time before the delete>` might show you the data and allow you to retrieve it?

Comment: Autocommit is not enabled.  It is still in the same session.  I still have the window open, and no disconnect took place yet.  
Script window are showing:
234,084 rows deleted.
75,440 rows deleted.
Error starting at line : 28 in command -
delete from TIMESHEET where event_id in (select event_id from temp_events)

Error at Command Line : 28 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
01013. 00000 -  "user requested cancel of current operation"

Comment: Hmm, you said "the temp_events table had...", but that's the table you just created; if you haven't committed then that table will be empty. How many records are and were in `event_rev` and `event_tasks`? Did you rollback from the script or with the rollback button (F12) - if the button, what does the Messages - log window show?

Comment: event_rev had 234K records and event_tasks had 75K.  I was not planning on deleting everything.
And no, Flashback is not enabled.
temp_events would have had about 800 records.  But after the rollback I did not recheck, and have dropped and recreated that table in the mean time.

Comment: Alex, see my answer below. You may post that as an answer and I will accept your answer as the solution for you to get points.

Comment: @user1208908 - you might as well accept your own answer really, I'd just be duplicating that with a few doc links. Though you could have inserted straight into `event_rev`. Would still be nice to understand how the deletes were committed, if they were - not sure now as you said you didn't check. Maybe you dropped and recreated the table *before* the rollback, since DDL implicitly commits? Anyway, glad you got your data back...

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.  Thanks Alex Poole.

I ran the following and it actually populated the new table with data:

```
Create table EVENT_REV_RESTORE AS 
select * from EVENT_REV
AS OF TIMESTAMP
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-28 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```